# Movesense sensor not broadcasting after firmware update

Tags: android, bluetooth, dfu, movesense

I've update the sensor with the latest version of the firmware from bitbucket, posted in the bin folder. I didn't build the firmware myself but used the plain_app firmware. After i did the update with the movesense sample app i cant seem to find the sensors anymore. Is this a common problem and how do i solve this?

if seen this issue:
https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/issues/4/plain_app-doesnt-connect-via-ble
but it when i downloaded the firmware the issue was already resolved.

link of the firmware i [downloaded](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/02ba6cc8d5418953b11b19ad6ff83ba6b1cff1bf/samples/plain_app/bin/movesense_dfu.zip?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Please provide full link from where You downloaded binary.

Comment: Can you clarify how the sensor appears now? If the led is lit all the time it's still in the DFU mode which means that the updated did not go thru. Also take battery off and back on should restart the sensor.

Comment: The sensors seem to be completely offline(no blinking,no bluetooh broadcast), i got one stuck in DFU modes which i also cant connect to. i tried different phones and batteries

Comment: After You will restart Movesense ( battery off / on) You see single LED blink? or LED is still visible?

Comment: @kensleebos Do You have JIG ? And You can re-flash Movesense device with new software?

Comment: @Esperanz0 i don't have a jig, i send my sensors back to movesense so that they can reset them.

Answer (score 0):

If Your Movesense stuck in DFU mode (red led is always visible) 
for now You can use this and try to flash Movesense once again ( this will be implemented into sample app and will be ready soon).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox&hl=en

Comment: The sensor is not flashing any lights at all. No response whatsoever. So reflashing wont work as i cant connect with the sensor

Comment: Hmm, it looks like eitherit doesn't get any power (you did try with another battery?) or that the DFU update broke the bootloader (which it shouldn't). If there is no valid software on the device the bootloader should automatically go to DFU mode. If it doesn't work with another known good battery, I'm afraid your device is briked. The only way to recover it is with the programming JIG.

Comment: I tested this binary and there is no problem with binary. Also Movesense didn't stuck in DFU mode. Please buy new battery and check with new one before we will create BUG for this.

Comment: I tried other new batteries, which doesn't change a thing. I will try to get my hands on a programming jig.